# How do I disable keep alive with HTTPClient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I am using [HTTPClient](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/).

Is there a way to disable keep-alive/persistent connections when making a request? Is this even possible if the server that serves the web pages has keep-alive on?

If it's not possible to do with HTTPClient, is it possible to do with other libraries such as Net:HTTP or Curb?

Comment: Why do you want to disable keep alive? Maybe you just need to extend keep alive timeout?

Comment: Because I want to see if it is causing issues with multi-threading. The question still stands.